# More meaningful error message in my code logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I have the following logic bellow, which is for my test, currently when this test fails it gives output expected 6, but was 26.

My goal is to modify the if logic or assert message to say something like if workflow status does not equal expectedWorkflowStatus print a error message
saying expected workflow to be sent, but was chilling. How would I modify the below code to give a more meaningful error message?

```
int expectedWorkflowStatus = 6; //SEND
int retry = 0;
int WorkflowStatusId = -1; //Currently this is 26

while (retry++ < 2)
{
    _context.PCWindowContext.LongWait();
    WorkflowStatusId = Helpers.SqlHelper.GetScalar<int>
        (conn_string_bumi, sql_bumi, "WorkflowStatusId");

    //perhaps give a more meaning full error message.
    if (WorkflowStatusId == expectedWorkflowStatus) 
       break;
}

Assert.AreEqual(expectedWorkflowStatus, WorkflowStatusId);
```

Comment: Do you have an enum or some sort of lookup for WorkflowStatusId => (human readable) string?

Comment: @Fildor No they are just coming as Ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this overload

```
public static void AreEqual (object expected, object actual, string message);
```

specify the message to be printed when the result is not equal to the expected value.

> The message to include in the exception when actual is not equal to expected. The message is shown in test results.

So modify the last line like this

```
Assert.AreEqual(expectedWorkflowStatus, WorkflowStatusId, 
    $"Hey hey, watch out my dear friend something went wrong... expect {expectedWorkflowStatus} but got {WorkflowStatusId}");
```